# dynamic controls data not store in database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

For signup users after getting some credentials, I am getting user's education means degree name and duration from_year and to_year into static controls below is the static controls code:

```
<table width="100%">
      <tr style = "text-align:center;">
         <td>
            <%= f.text_field :tf_Degree,placeholder: "Degree" %>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style = "text-align:center;">
         <td>
            From
            <%= f.select :fromyear, (1995..Time.now.year).to_a, :include_blank => {:year => "Select year"} %>
            to
            <%= f.select :toyear, (1995..Time.now.year).to_a, :include_blank => {:year => "Select year"} %>
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

And If I wants to enter further more education of user then I clicks on `add` button to add dynamic controls using jquery below is the dynamic controls code:

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td align="center">
            <table id="Controls">
            </table>

            <div><input value="Add" type="submit" /></div>
            <input id="valEdu" type="hidden" value="0" />

         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

And below is the jquery for creating dynamic controls:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[value='Add']").click(function(e)    {

            e.preventDefault();
            var hidval = $('#valEdu').val();
            if(hidval = 0)
            {
             hidval = 1;
            }
            else
            {
             hidval++;
            }  
            alert(hidval);

            var rownum=$("#Controls > tbody > tr").length;
            alert(rownum);
            var updated_row_num;
            if (rownum == 0)
            {
                updated_row_num=0;
            }
            else {
                updated_row_num=rownum/2;
            }

            // var field = $("#field").val();
            var year = new Date().getFullYear();

            var DDL_fromProfession = "<select name='ParametersFromSch["+ updated_row_num +"]' id='DDL_FromSchYear'>";
            for (var i = year; i >= 1950; --i) {
                DDL_fromProfession += "<option text='" + i + "' value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
            }
            DDL_fromProfession += "</select>";

                var DDL_ToProfession = "<select name='ParametersToSch["+ updated_row_num +"]'  id='DDL_ToSchYear'>";
                for (var j = year; j >= 1950; --j) {
                    if (j != year) {
                        DDL_ToProfession += "<option text='" + j + "' value='" + j + "'>" + j + "</option>";
                    }
                    else {
                        DDL_ToProfession += "<option text='Present' value='Present'>Present</option>";

                    }
                }
                DDL_ToProfession += "</select>";

     var input1 = "<input name='parametersSch["+ updated_row_num +"]' id='field' type='text' placeholder='Degree' style='text-align:center;' onfocus='WaterMarkSchool(this, event);' onblur='WaterMarkSchool(this, event);' />"
                var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' height='35px'>"
                + input1 + "</td></tr>";


var controls = "<tr><td>From "+ DDL_fromProfession + " To "+DDL_ToProfession+ "</td></tr>";
controls += "<br/><button type='button' class='btn_rmv'>Remove</button></td></tr>";

     $('#Controls').append(newRow);
     $('#Controls').append(controls);
     return false;
  });

            $('#Controls').on('click', '.btn_rmv', function() {
              alert("ali");
                var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2
                $('#Controls tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 2) + ')').remove();
                return false;
            });

 });
</script>
```

But the problem is that only static controls data is stored in db, and dynamic controls are not store in db, for resolve this issue, I add hidden control and in the jquery I am checking that If hidden control value is equal to zero, then its save 1 else its increament like below:

```
 var hidval = $('#valEdu').val();
                if(hidval = 0)
                {
                 hidval = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                 hidval++;
                }  
                alert(hidval);
```

And in the controllers page I am checking the condition of hidden controls:

{for storing static data)

```
 if !params[:Educations][:tf_Degree].blank? && params[:Educations][:tf_Degree] != "Degree" 
           @Degree = params[:Educations][:tf_Degree]
           @From = params[:Educations][:fromyear]
           @To = params[:Educations][:toyear]
           @Education = Education.new( :UserID => current_user.id, :SchoolName => @Degree, :SchoolFrom => @From, :SchoolTo => @To )
           @Education.save
        end
        {for storing dynamic data}
        if params[:valEdu].present? && params[:valEdu] > 0 {here I am checking hidden value}
           params[:parametersSch].each do |keydeg, degree|
            if !degree.nil?
               @degree=degree
                puts @degree
                params[:ParametersFromSch].each do |keyfrom, from|
                if keydeg== keyfrom
                   @from=from
                end
            end
            params[:ParametersToSch].each do |keyto, to|
                if keydeg==keyto
                   @to=to          
                end
            end
            @Education = Education.new( :UserID => current_user.id, :SchoolName => @degree, :SchoolFrom => @from, :SchoolTo => @to )
            @Education.save
           end
          end
        end
        #render 'index'
        redirect_to '/default'
      end
```

in the above I am checking that It hidden control value is grater 0 then it stores data in db, but its not working, kindly help me, waiting for your reply. 
Thanks

Comment: Hope this will help. http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't really understand everything but I noticed at least 2 errors in your code.

First, in your javascript code

```
if(hidval = 0){
  ...
}
else{
  ...
}
```

In this piece of code, I think that hidval is at the beginning a string, so it is not `0` but `'0'`. Now, `hidval = 0` is a condition that will always return false ! What you want to write is `hidval == 0` I think. Also, I don't understand the condition, what do you need it for, because at last, you always do `a + 1` no ? So Instead of the whole condition, why not write :
`hidval++`. It will have the same behavior.

Finally, in your ruby code :

```
params[:valEdu] > 0
```

will probably raise an error like : `ArgumentError: comparison of String with 0 failed`

Because query parameters are always string, maybe you can do

```
params[:valEdu].to_i > 0
```

Hum, and if you want to update the value of the hidden input, it is not how you do it, here you are just updating the value of the javascript variable, but not touching the DOM element, what you can write for that is :

```
a = $('#valEdu').val();
$('#valEdu').val(++a);
```

I don't know if it is an answer but at least it will help you go further I guess !